# Unreal Engine 4.18 - Adding c++ feature gives me error

Tags: visual-studio, unreal-engine4

I created a new Blueprint project with First Person template, and then I want to add the Third Person c++ feature. However, as soon as I do, it gives me the errors shown below

[image]

[image]

And if I try to build the solution in visual studio, i get these errors

[image]

I have tried both with VS community 2015 and 2017, reinstalled them both as well as unreal engine. I even reinstalled and formatted all my hard drives, including windows. Still the same problem.

Comment: For future reference I think reformatting your hard drive is a bit extreme to fix a compiler error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @CoryKramer - Depends on the error. Simply reformatting may not be enough. Some errors may drive one to abstain from all technology.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found *one* solution. **I started the project with the C++ template instead of the blueprint one** for First Person, then it let me add the C++ feature without problems. Seems like you can't add C++ features to a freshly started Blueprint project, unless I'm missing something.

When I created it with blueprint, I could still add the blueprint feature for Third Person but not the C++.